# Yarn add for a package slower than npm install | linking dependencies very slow

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

Whenever I try to add a new package with yarn it is slower and linking dependency takes too much time.

Does it reinstall all packages or what? I moved from npm to yarn so it is faster looks opposite is happening. Is there a way to skip linking dependencies?

```
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "@react-pdf/renderer > react-reconciler@0.23.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.0.0".
warning " > react-compound-timer@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.8.6".warning " > react-countdown-circle-timer@2.5.3" has unmet peer dependency "prop-types@>=15.7.0".
warning " > react-markdown@6.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "@types/react@>=16".
warning " > react-qr-reader@2.2.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@~16".
warning " > react-qr-reader@2.2.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@~16".
warning " > reaptcha@1.7.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.6.3".
warning " > eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.1" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-react-hooks@^4 || ^3 || ^2.3.0 || ^1.7.0".
warning " > file-loader@6.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
```

Comment: @jonsharpe @ dee Any solution?

Comment: docker if you use a volume on windows it is slower.